# ASP - Page Not Loading until SendEmail function has ran

Tags: html, asp-classic, subroutine

I have an ASP page that receives data from the previous page through a form.

The ASP page:

1. Connects to Database
2. Updates Database
3. Loads HTML to say your form has been submitted
4. Email routine that sends a confirmation.

However, the page is not loading until the email routine has ran, even though it's the last routine to be called.

The call "SendEmail" routine, which is at the bottom of the page in a Sub, is called right after the HTML is loaded

```
</html>

<%

Call SendEmail

Sub SendEmail

End Sub
%>
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Cheers

John

Comment: Of course it doesn't - ASP is server side, therefore all of your code will run on the server prior to sending its response to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Classic ASP, like ASP.NET, PHP and so on, are all server side languages.  That means the the script that populates a page is executed prior to a response being sent to the client.  As an example:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div><h1>This is a test</h1><p>Some random Lorem Ipsum in a box.</p></div>
        <%Response.Write("This is also a test<br/>")%>
        <p>Some other gobbledegook.</p>
        <%Response.Write("37 + 59 = " & (37+59))%>
        <%SendMail("Whatever message.")%>
    </body>
</html>
<%Response.Write("Something else here.")%>
```

All this code will execute on the server side before returning something like:

## This is a test

Some random Lorem Ipsum in a box.

This is also a test

Some other gobbledegook.

37 + 59 = 96
*...(SendMail would execute here)...*
Something else here.

If you want sections to run in unison then you'll have to consider invoking them with JavaScript, jQuery or some other similar JavaScript based plugin, or alternatively using (*cough*) a selection of `iframe`s (gah! nasty!).

Answer (score -1):

```
</html>

<%
Response.Flush 'sends buffered HTML output immediately.
Call SendEmail

Sub SendEmail

End Sub
%>
```

Comment: I now think it's possibly more to do with the server than the code because the simple buffer/flush routine doesn't work either

Comment: Flushing the buffer will not solve this problem at all - it's all to do with the expectation of how a page executes.

Comment: I presumed there would be ASP within the body